# Optimisation in R - giving each occasion a group leader, every person should be chosen at least once

Tags: r, optimization, while-loop, dplyr, sampling

I'm trying to create a schedule for my class.
I have 38 students. I will meet them on 11 (5+6) occasions (BES and PBL).

For each occasion they have been randomly sorted into 8 groups, resulting in 6 groups of 5 and 2 groups of 4.

For each occasion, I want to choose one student to lead that group - a Leader. I would ideally like every student to be the leader of a group once.

I at most manage to get 36 unique leaders through the following manner.
Is there a way to run an optimisation in R such that I want an objective function that maximises the number of unique leaders?  My guess is that the current limitation is by the way they are randomly sampled into groups.

```
set.seed(13)

studentlist <- data.frame(Name=as.character(c(paste0("A",seq(1:38)))))

studentlist$PBL1 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                 labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$PBL2 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$PBL3 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$PBL4 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$PBL5 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$BES1 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$BES2 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$BES3 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$BES4 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$BES5 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))

studentlist$BES6 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)), 
                                  labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist <- as.data.frame(studentlist)

BES_leaders <- studentlist %>% select(Name, BES1:BES6) %>%  pivot_longer(cols = "BES1":"BES6",names_to = "Occassion",values_to = "Group")

#initiate i to count set.seed
i <- 1
#initialise best solution
BES_leaders3 <-  data.frame()

while(length(unique(BES_leaders2$Leader))<=36) {
  set.seed(i)
  return.i <- i
  
  BES_leaders_2 <- BES_leaders %>% nest_by(Occassion,Group) %>% mutate(Leader= sample(c(data$Name),1,replace = FALSE)) %>% select(Occassion,Group,Leader)
  BES_leaders2 <- as.data.frame(BES_leaders_2)
  
  BES_leaders3 <- if(length(unique(BES_leaders2$Leader)) > length(unique(BES_leaders3$Leader))){BES_leaders2} else {BES_leaders3}
  i <- i+1
  print(length(unique(BES_leaders3$Leader)))
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want and what your data represents.  I.e. what is an occasion and what is a leader?  Are you randomly generating clusters of students for each occasion?  Your problem does read like an optimization assignment problem with side constraints.  I.e. constraints on who is assigned to what.  Those problems can be solved in R using Integer Programming.  There are packages to do that.  Perhaps you can add some clarity to your problem definition.

Comment: @SteveM I've edited for clarity. Does it read better now?

Comment: It reads like you have 6 groups x 11 occasions = 66 groups.  So why not just assign the 38 students once to 38 of the 66 groups as leaders and then randomize the remaining 37 students for the groups assigned leaders and all 38 where who the leader is, is not important?

Comment: Correction for above.  I see not 6 but 8 groups are created so 88 groups in total.  So if you have 38 students, you could assign each to be a leader twice, i.e. 76 out of 88 specific leader assignments.

Comment: @SteveM , could you provide an example in a reply to the question so I can mark it as a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could formulate this as an optimization problem:

Introduce the notation:

```
   i : set of occasions (11)
   s : set of students (38)
   g : set of groups (8)
```

Calculate

```
  gsi[g,s,i] = 1 if student s is in group g at occasion i
               0 otherwise
  this is calculated from your studentlist
```

Define variables:

```
  leader[i,s] = 1 if student s is leader at occasion i
                0 otherwise
  countTimes[s] : number of times student s is a leader
  max : max(countTimes[s])
  min : min(countTimes[s])
```

Construct the model:

```
  minimize max - min
  subject to 
     sum(s, gsi[g,s,i]*leader[i,s]) = 1  for all i,g  
     countTimes[s] = sum(i,leader[i,s])
     countTimes[s] <= max    for all s
     countTimes[s] >= min    for all s
```

For me this gives:

```
----     95 PARAMETER lead  

                     A1          A2          A3          A4          A5          A6          A7          A8          A9

PBL2.group4                                                                       1
PBL3.group6                                   1
PBL4.group2                                                           1
PBL4.group4                                                                                   1
PBL4.group7           1
PBL5.group6                       1
PBL5.group7                                               1
BES1.group1                                                                                                           1
BES1.group4                                                           1
BES1.group8           1
BES2.group3                                                                                               1
BES2.group4                                               1
BES3.group4                                                                                   1
BES3.group7                                                                                                           1
BES4.group5           1
BES4.group6                                   1
BES4.group8                                                                                               1
BES5.group1                                               1
BES5.group2                                                           1
BES5.group3                                                                       1
BES6.group1                       1
BES6.group6                                                                                                           1

          +         A10         A11         A12         A13         A14         A15         A16         A17         A18

PBL1.group1                                                                       1
PBL1.group2           1
PBL1.group4                                                           1
PBL1.group8                                                                                               1
PBL2.group1                                                                                                           1
PBL2.group7                                                                                   1
PBL3.group4                                                                                               1
PBL5.group2                       1
PBL5.group4                                               1
PBL5.group5                                                                                               1
BES1.group7                                               1
BES2.group1                                                                                   1
BES2.group5                                                           1
BES4.group1                       1
BES4.group4                                   1
BES5.group5                                   1
BES5.group8           1
BES6.group7                                                                       1
BES6.group8                                                                                                           1

          +         A19         A20         A21         A22         A23         A24         A25         A26         A27

PBL1.group3                                                           1
PBL1.group5                                               1
PBL2.group2                                                                                                           1
PBL2.group3           1
PBL2.group8                                               1
PBL3.group2                                                                                   1
PBL3.group7                       1
PBL4.group1                                                                                                           1
PBL4.group3                                                                                               1
PBL4.group6                       1
PBL5.group1                                                                       1
PBL5.group3                                                           1
BES3.group1                                   1
BES3.group2                                                                                                           1
BES4.group3                                                                                   1
BES4.group7                       1
BES5.group4                                                                                               1
BES5.group6                                   1
BES6.group2                                   1
BES6.group4                                                                       1
BES6.group5           1

          +         A28         A29         A30         A31         A32         A33         A34         A35         A36

PBL1.group7                                                                                               1
PBL2.group5                                               1
PBL2.group6           1
PBL3.group1                                                           1
PBL3.group3                                               1
PBL4.group5                                   1
PBL4.group8                                                                                   1
PBL5.group8                                               1
BES1.group2                                                                                                           1
BES1.group3                                                                       1
BES1.group5                                   1
BES1.group6                       1
BES2.group2                                                                                                           1
BES2.group6                                                                       1
BES2.group7                       1
BES2.group8                                                                                   1
BES3.group5           1
BES3.group6                                                                                               1
BES3.group8                                                                       1
BES4.group2                                                           1
BES5.group7                                                                                                           1

          +         A37         A38

PBL1.group6                       1
PBL3.group5                       1
PBL3.group8           1
BES3.group3                       1
BES6.group3           1
```

Each student is two or three times a leader. I did not use R but a commercial tool. I will see if I can do this in R.

An R implementation can look like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

numStudents <- 38
numGroups <- 8
numMeetings <- 11


# code from question
set.seed(13)
studentlist <- data.frame(Name=as.character(c(paste0("A",seq(1:38)))))
studentlist$PBL1 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$PBL2 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$PBL3 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$PBL4 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$PBL5 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$BES1 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$BES2 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$BES3 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$BES4 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$BES5 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist$BES6 <- sample(factor(rep(1:8, length.out=nrow(studentlist)),labels=paste0(1:8)))
studentlist <- as.data.frame(studentlist)
studentlist

# form 3d binary matrix  
gsi <- array(0L,dim=c(numGroups,numStudents,numMeetings))
for (s in 1:numStudents)
  for (i in 1:numMeetings) { 
    g <- studentlist[s,i+1]  
    gsi[g,s,i] = 1L
  }


result <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(leader[i,s], i=1:numMeetings, s=1:numStudents, type = "binary") %>%
  add_variable(count[s], s=1:numStudents) %>%
  add_variable(max) %>%
  add_variable(min) %>%
  set_objective(max-min, "min") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(gsi[g,s,i]*leader[i,s], s=1:numStudents) == 1, i=1:numMeetings, g=1:numGroups) %>%
  add_constraint(count[s] == sum_expr(leader[i,s], i=1:numMeetings), s=1:numStudents) %>%
  add_constraint(count[s] <= max, s=1:numStudents) %>%
  add_constraint(count[s] >= min, s=1:numStudents) %>%
  add_constraint(min >= 1) %>%
  # too slow to prove optimality. We stop after 200 seconds.
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver="glpk", verbose=T, tm_limit=20000)) %>% 
  get_solution(leader[i,s])  %>%
  filter(value > 0) 

result2 <- matrix(0L,nrow=numStudents,ncol=numMeetings)
for (k in 1:nrow(result)) {
  i <- result$i[k]
  s <- result$s[k]
  result2[s,i] <- 1
}
rownames(result2) <- studentlist$Name
colnames(result2) <- colnames(studentlist)[-1]
result2
```

The solver is not strong enough to prove optimality, but we should find an optimal solution in (much) less than our time limit of 200 seconds (objective=1). The `result2` output looks like:

```
> result2
    PBL1 PBL2 PBL3 PBL4 PBL5 BES1 BES2 BES3 BES4 BES5 BES6
A1     0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
A2     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
A3     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
A4     1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
A5     1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
A6     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
A7     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0
A8     0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
A9     1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
A10    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
A11    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
A12    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
A13    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
A14    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
A15    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1
A16    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
A17    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
A18    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
A19    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
A20    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
A21    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
A22    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
A23    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
A24    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
A25    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
A26    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
A27    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
A28    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
A29    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
A30    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
A31    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
A32    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
A33    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
A34    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
A35    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
A36    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
A37    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
A38    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reduced problem assigning 5 leaders to 10 groups of 5, (each person made a leader twice)

```
m1 <- replicate(10, sample(1:5, 5)) #randomize 10 groups of 5
leaders <- c(1:5, 1:5) # create the leader top row
m2 <- rbind(leaders, m1)  # bind the leader row to the random groups
m3 <- apply(m2, 2, unique) # remove the redundant leaders from each group
```

You would do the same but for 38 students across 76 groups.  Then simply randomize the remaining 12 groups assigning leaders arbitrarily and cbind those to m3.

Answer (score 1):

This solution follows something like SteveM's approach of assigning the leaders sequentially to occasions and groups.  However, it explicity deals with the two group sizes and randomizes students across groups and occasions. It uses only base R and tidyverse.  All students are assigned as leaders either two or three times.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    set.seed(13)
    students <- c(paste0("A",seq(1:38))) %>% factor()
    n_students <- length(students)
    n_occasions <- 11
#  
    n_memb_1 <- 4  # number of members in each of first set of groups
    n_grps_1 <- 6  # number of groups in the first set
    n_memb_2 <- 3  # number of members in each of second set of groups
    n_grps_2 <- 2  # number of groups in the second set
#
#  create sequences for groups and member sets
#
    member_sets <- c(rep(1: n_memb_1, times = n_grps_1), rep(1:n_memb_2, times = n_grps_2))
    group_sets <- c(rep(1:n_grps_1,each = n_memb_1), rep((n_grps_1+1):(n_grps_1 + n_grps_2),each = n_memb_2))
#
    n_groups <- n_grps_1 + n_grps_2
#   
#  make vectors of leaders for all occasions and groups
#   
   leaders <- unlist(rep(students, ceiling(n_groups*n_occasions/n_students) ))[1:(n_occasions*n_groups)]
#  make an empty tibble object to collect results  
   group_assign <- tibble()
#
#  loop over occasions and collect results into group_assign
# 
   for( i_oc in 0:(n_occasions-1)) {
  
# get leaders for this occasion      
      occasion_leaders <- leaders[(i_oc*n_groups+1):((i_oc+1)*n_groups)]
# make list of students without leaders and randimize them
      members <- setdiff(students, occasion_leaders) %>%
                sample(n_students - n_groups) 
# collect into tibble for this occasion and combine with other occasions
       group_assign <-   tibble(occasion = i_oc+1, 
                                group = group_sets, 
                               leader = occasion_leaders[group_sets],
                               member_number = member_sets,
                               member = members) %>% 
                          bind_rows(group_assign)
  
      }
 #
 # format for display
 #
    group_assign <- group_assign %>% arrange(occasion, group) %>%
                    pivot_wider(names_from = member_number, 
                               values_from = member,
                               names_prefix = "Member_")
```

The first 10 rows of the result are:

```
# A tibble: 88 x 7
   occasion group leader Member_1 Member_2 Member_3 Member_4
      <dbl> <int> <fct>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
          1     1 A1     A32      A11      A13      A18     
          1     2 A2     A21      A14      A24      A30     
          1     3 A3     A12      A27      A25      A35     
          1     4 A4     A23      A36      A20      A9      
          1     5 A5     A33      A16      A26      A38     
          1     6 A6     A31      A34      A15      A22     
          1     7 A7     A28      A17      A37      NA      
          1     8 A8     A29      A19      A10      NA      
          2     1 A9     A38      A4       A2       A1      
          2     2 A10    A27      A32      A34      A30
```